# Array.prototype.concat not behaving like expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var a = [{}];
var b = [];
var c = a.concat(b);

console.log(a[0] === c[0]);
c[0] = undefined;
console.log("a[0] value: ", a[0]);
console.log("c[0] value: ", c[0]);
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat:

> Object references (and not the actual object): concat copies object
>   references into the new array. Both the original and new array refer
>   to the same object. That is, if a referenced object is modified, the
>   changes are visible to both the new and original arrays. This includes
>   elements of array arguments that are also arrays.

I am expecting the value of `a[0]` to change to undefined when I modify the `c[0]` because both, `a[0]` and `c[0]` hold references to the same object, but clearly this is not what is happening here. What am I missing?

Comment: try `a === c` notice that it is false.

Comment: You didn't change the object/reference, you replaced it with a new item (`undefined`). Changing the referenced object, e.g. `c[0].newProperty = "Hello World"` would show a change in both `a[0]` and `c[0]`.

Comment: @TylerRoper Oh my.. That's what happens when you have so many sleepless nights. Thanks.

Comment: You can modify Object himself by reference like Object.myVar but if you change Object of one of the array, it's not the same Object so you break reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Object references (and not the actual object): concat copies object references into the new array.

It's true that the object *reference* is copied, but the copied reference is still independent of the first reference. Assigning to the array element only changes that reference. In effect, after `concat()` you have a[0] and c[0] pointing at the same object.

```
a[0].abc = "abc"
console.log(c[0].abc); // will print "abc".
```

But assigning to c[0] only overwrites the reference with undefined, leaving the reference in a[0] (and the object) untouched.

Answer (score -1):

[mozilla JS Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
"The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array."
concat method returns a totally new array object, independent of the arguments.